# How to insert the dates from a table to another table for two different conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get the date (b.date) information with a condition (i. e. When c. Code=001 then b. Date should fetch the dates from past one month,  and for the c. code other than 001  then b. Date should be greater than sysdate)  from  table b and table c.
Please find the below explanation for the same. 
Create Table A
As (select b. Date, c. Code from table b, table c
Where b. Code=c.code
And  b. Date  should fetch the dates from past one month when c. code =001
 and b. Date should fetch the dates from greater than sysdate when c. Code is other than 001)

Table A should populated with the below  the  date and code columns
For ex

```
Code       Date
Code001    7/01/19 
Code001    8/01/19
...
Code111    7/02/19
```

Could you please tell me how can i achieve this using oracle sql?

Please let me know if you need any other information on the issue or if my explanation is confusing.

Thanks for your support,
Vani.

Comment: Please, can you post an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the source code you are running? The question in not very clear to be honest.

Comment: Please, use only the correct database tag. You should edit your question, add some input (sample) data and the expected output/s.

Answer (score 0):

I am not so sure about the question, however based on what you have provided, I am doing a union of two queries(#Oracle Sql) ..I understand this would not be an optimized query depending how large is the table, it may consume resources because of cartesian product .. please see below:

```
select b.date,c.code from <table> b,<table> c 
where b.code=c.code 
  and c.code='001'
  and b.date>= trunc(add_months(sysdate, -1),'MM') and b.date<trunc(sysdate, 'MM')
union
select b.date,c.code from <table> b,<table> c 
where b.code=c.code 
  and c.code<>'001'
  and b.date>sysdate;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have a Table called A which will use the date and code from table B and C. And Table A will be created dynamically based on the table b and table c data. And table A should has the dates from past one for the code 001 ,and for the codes is other than 001 then dates should be from greater than sysdate.Let me know if this explanation helps in understanding my question.

Comment: Then won't the above query work in this case?, as the first part of union is fetching the dates from previous month and code is '001' .. then second part is fetching the dates which are > sysdate and code is <> '001' .. you can create another table A with create table query using above select.. hope this helps

Comment: I will try the solution suggested and update you.Thanks again for the help Rhythm.

Comment: Thanks Rhythm. The solution you suggested worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to achieve this by implementing the logic in the `WHERE` clause.

```
WHERE 
    ( c.Code = '001' AND b.Date >= TRUNC(sysdate, 'mm')
    OR b.Date >= sysdate
```

Or maybe (if you are storing dates without time)

```
WHERE 
    ( c.Code = '001' AND b.Date >= TRUNC(sysdate, 'mm')
    OR b.Date >= TRUNC(sysdate)
```

NB : the date functions widely vary depending on the RDBMS ; the above solution is for Oracle. In MySQL, you would do :

```
WHERE 
    ( c.Code = '001' AND b.Date >= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01')
    OR b.Date >= NOW() -- or CURDATE()
```